# How can I get the correct path to resources folder in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Well I am working on an application with SpringMVC, I have to store some pictures in my resources folder, I need to have the correct path that will work on my computer and after deploying the application, I've tried many things but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is my configuration and what I've tried.

servlet-context.xml

```
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

                        <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

                        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
                        <annotation-driven />

                        <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
                        <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
                        <resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />  

                        <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
                        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                        </beans:bean>

                        <context:component-scan base-package="com.hpcdg.quality" /> 



                    </beans:beans>
```

the Controller

```
                             if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                                    try {
                                        mod.addAttribute("objet", resourceLoader.getResource("/resources/images_Emp/"+this.GenerateName(8)+".png").getFile());
                                        System.out.println(resourceLoader.getResource("/resources/images_Emp/"+this.GenerateName(8)+".png").getFile());
                                        file.transferTo(resourceLoader.getResource("/resources/images_Emp/"+this.GenerateName(8)+".png").getFile());

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException("Product Image saving failed", e);
                                    }
                               }

                            return "/QL/Ajouts";
                        }
```

When I display the path: I get something with metadata of the workspace, what I need is to have something that go directly to the resources folder in the webapp of my application.

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `new ClassPathResource("images_Emp" + File.separator + this.GenerateName(8)+".png")`

`File.separator` makes your path platform independent